# Группировка виджетов в менеджерах компоновки

Tags: python, pyqt, qlayout, pyqt6, qgridlayout

Есть виджет, в который через `QGridLayout` добавлены:

- верхний блок (содержит `labels` и `lineEdits`), 
  состоит из двух строк (два `QHBoxLayout`);
- левый блок (только кнопки);
- центр (в этом примере пустой).

Что не получается сделать:

1. Верхний блок:
   1.1 Верхняя строка.
   Тут будет допустимо сильно увеличить `lineEdit`, что сожмёт поля и метки, так что тут норм.
   1.2 Нижняя строка.
   Надо сгруппировать как на картинке (т.е. плотно прижать метки к полям в группах, а не все со всеми), не увеличивая в размерах `editLine`.
2. Блок слева:
   2.1 В `groupBox` сжать по вертикали с минимальным space между кнопками и краями.
   2.2 Кнопки ниже `groupBox` - верхние прижать к верху с большим space,
   одну нижнюю прижать к низу с тем же большим space.

Картинка 1 - скриншот того что есть.
Картинка 2 - как надо сделать.

В коде использован *PySide6*. Если у вас *PyQt*, то это то же самое, в импортах надо заменить на *PyQt6*.

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtCore import *

class Widget1(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(Widget1, self).__init__(parent)

    self.createTopWidget()
    self.createLeftWidget()
    self.createCenterWidget()

    mainLayout = QGridLayout()
    mainLayout.addLayout(self.topVLayout, 0, 0, 1, 7)
    mainLayout.addLayout(self.leftLayout, 1, 0)
    mainLayout.addLayout(self.centerLayout, 1, 1, 2, 7)
    self.setLayout(mainLayout)
    self.setGeometry(100, 100, 1000, 700)
    

def createTopWidget(self) :
    label1 = QLabel("label1")
    label2 = QLabel("label2")
    label3 = QLabel("label3")
    label4 = QLabel("label4")
    label5 = QLabel("label5")
    label6 = QLabel("label6")
    label7 = QLabel("label7")
    label8 = QLabel("label8")
    label9 = QLabel("label9")
    lineEdit1 = QLineEdit()
    lineEdit1.setFixedWidth(200)
    lineEdit2 = QLineEdit()
    lineEdit2.setFixedWidth(50)
    lineEdit3 = QLineEdit()
    lineEdit3.setFixedWidth(200)
    lineEdit4 = QLineEdit()
    lineEdit4.setFixedWidth(30)
    lineEdit5 = QLineEdit()
    lineEdit5.setFixedWidth(30)
    lineEdit6 = QLineEdit()
    lineEdit6.setFixedWidth(60)
    lineEdit7 = QLineEdit()
    lineEdit7.setFixedWidth(30)
      
    topHLayout_1 = QHBoxLayout()
    topHLayout_1.addWidget(label1)
    topHLayout_1.addWidget(lineEdit1)
    topHLayout_1.addWidget(label2)
    topHLayout_1.addWidget(lineEdit2)
    topHLayout_1.addWidget(label3)
    topHLayout_1.addWidget(lineEdit3)
    
    topHLayout_2 = QHBoxLayout()
    topHLayout_2.addWidget(label4)
    topHLayout_2.addWidget(lineEdit4)
    topHLayout_2.addWidget(label5)
    topHLayout_2.addWidget(lineEdit5)
    topHLayout_2.addWidget(label6)
    topHLayout_2.addWidget(label7)
    topHLayout_2.addWidget(lineEdit6)
    topHLayout_2.addWidget(label7)
    topHLayout_2.addWidget(label8)    
    topHLayout_2.addWidget(label9)
    topHLayout_2.addWidget(lineEdit7)
    
    self.topVLayout = QVBoxLayout()
    self.topVLayout.addLayout(topHLayout_1)
    self.topVLayout.addLayout(topHLayout_2)

def createLeftWidget(self):
    self.leftLayout = QVBoxLayout()
    
    button1 = QPushButton("btn1")
    button2 = QPushButton("btn2")
    button3 = QPushButton("btn3")
    groupbox = QGroupBox("groupBox")
    vbox1 = QVBoxLayout()
    vbox1.addWidget(button1)
    vbox1.addWidget(button2)
    vbox1.addWidget(button3)
    groupbox.setLayout(vbox1)
    self.leftLayout.addWidget(groupbox)
    
    button4 = QPushButton("btn4")
    button5 = QPushButton("btn5")
    button6 = QPushButton("btn6")
    button7 = QPushButton("btn7")
    self.leftLayout.addWidget(button4)
    self.leftLayout.addWidget(button5)
    self.leftLayout.addWidget(button6)
    self.leftLayout.addWidget(button7)

def createCenterWidget(self):
    self.centerLayout = QVBoxLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget1()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

---

[image: Скриншот]

---

Картинка 2 - как надо сделать.

[image: Что надо получить]

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
'''
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtCore import *
'''
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Widget1(QWidget):                                         # ? QDialog
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget1, self).__init__(parent)

        self.createTopWidget()
        self.createLeftWidget()
#        self.createCenterWidget()
        self.createRightWidget()        

# -----------------------------> vvvv <---------------------------------------
        mainLayout = QGridLayout(self)
#        mainLayout.addLayout(self.topVLayout, 0, 0, 1, 7)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.top_frame, 0, 0, 1, 7)
# ---------------> ^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <---------------------------------        
#        mainLayout.addLayout(self.leftLayout, 1, 0)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.left_frame, 1, 0)        
# ---------------> ^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <--------------------------------- 
#        mainLayout.addLayout(self.centerLayout, 1, 1, 2, 7)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.right_frame, 1, 1, 1, 6)        
# ---------------> ^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <--------------------------------- 

        mainLayout.setRowStretch(0, 0)                                   # +++
        mainLayout.setRowStretch(1, 1)                                   # +++
#        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

    def createTopWidget(self) :
# ----------------------------> vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv <-----------------------    
        self.top_frame = QFrame(objectName='top_frame')                   # +++
        
        label1 = QLabel("label1")
        label2 = QLabel("label2")
        label3 = QLabel("label3")
        lineEdit1 = QLineEdit()
#        lineEdit1.setFixedWidth(200)
        lineEdit2 = QLineEdit()
        lineEdit2.setFixedWidth(50)
        lineEdit3 = QLineEdit()
#        lineEdit3.setFixedWidth(200)        
        
        label4 = QLabel("label4")
        label5 = QLabel("label5")
        label6 = QLabel("label6")
        label7 = QLabel("label7", objectName='label7')                   # +     
        label8 = QLabel("label8", objectName='label8')                   # +
        label8.setFixedWidth(30)       
        label9 = QLabel("label9")

        lineEdit4 = QLineEdit()
        lineEdit4.setFixedWidth(30)
        lineEdit5 = QLineEdit()
        lineEdit5.setFixedWidth(30)
        lineEdit6 = QLineEdit('le6')
        lineEdit6.setFixedWidth(50)           # 60
        lineEdit7 = QLineEdit()
        lineEdit7.setFixedWidth(30)
          
        topHLayout_1 = QHBoxLayout()
        topHLayout_1.addWidget(label1)
        topHLayout_1.addWidget(lineEdit1)
        topHLayout_1.addWidget(label2)
        topHLayout_1.addWidget(lineEdit2)
        topHLayout_1.addWidget(label3)
        topHLayout_1.addWidget(lineEdit3)
        
        topHLayout_2 = QHBoxLayout()
        topHLayout_2.addWidget(label4)
        topHLayout_2.addWidget(lineEdit4)
        topHLayout_2.addWidget(label5)
        topHLayout_2.addWidget(lineEdit5)
        topHLayout_2.addWidget(label6)
        
        topHLayout_2.addStretch(4)                                         # +++
        
        topHLayout_2.addWidget(label7)
        topHLayout_2.addWidget(lineEdit6)
# ?        topHLayout_2.addWidget(label7)
        topHLayout_2.addWidget(label8)    
        topHLayout_2.addStretch(5)                                        # +++
        topHLayout_2.addWidget(label9)
        topHLayout_2.addWidget(lineEdit7) 
        
        self.topVLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.top_frame)           # + self.top_frame
        self.topVLayout.addLayout(topHLayout_1)
        self.topVLayout.addLayout(topHLayout_2)

    def createLeftWidget(self):
        self.left_frame = QFrame(objectName='left_frame')                  # +   
        self.leftLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.left_frame)                     # +  
        
        button1 = QPushButton("btn1")
        button2 = QPushButton("btn2")
        button3 = QPushButton("btn3")
        groupbox = QGroupBox("groupBox")
        vbox1 = QVBoxLayout(groupbox)
        vbox1.addWidget(button1)
        vbox1.addWidget(button2)
        vbox1.addWidget(button3)
        self.leftLayout.addWidget(groupbox)
        
        button4 = QPushButton("Btn 4")
        button5 = QPushButton("Btn 5")
        button6 = QPushButton("btn6")
        button7 = QPushButton("btn7")
        self.leftLayout.addStretch(1)                                      # + 
        self.leftLayout.addWidget(button4)
        self.leftLayout.addStretch(1)                                      # +
        self.leftLayout.addWidget(button5)
        self.leftLayout.addStretch(3)                                      # +
        self.leftLayout.addWidget(button6)
        self.leftLayout.addStretch(1)                                      # +        
        self.leftLayout.addWidget(button7)
        self.leftLayout.addStretch(1)                                      # +

    def createRightWidget(self):                            #createCenterWidget
        self.right_frame = QFrame(objectName='right_frame')                  # + 
        self.right_label = QLabel('Hello Right_Label',                       # +
            objectName='right_label', alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)              # +
        self.centerLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.right_frame)                    # +
        self.centerLayout.addWidget(self.right_label)                        # +
        

Stylesheet = '''
#top_frame {
    background: #20B2AA;
}    
#left_frame {
    background: #32CD32;
}    
#right_frame {
    background: #BA55D3;
}  
#label8, #label7 {
    background-color:  #f00;
    color:  #fff;
}
#right_label {
    font-size: 34px;
    color:  #fff;
}

'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    app.setStyleSheet(Stylesheet)                                      # +
    
    w = Widget1()
    w.resize(1000, 600)                                                # +
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это гениально! благодарю!!!1

Answer (score 1):

Набросай в QtDesigner (есть в пакете pyside6, смотри в папке Python/Scripts). Потом скомпилируй в py  через pyuic.

Между 5 и 6 кнопкой нужно добавить экспандер.

В GroupBox поправить поля и интервал, чтоб всё прижалось.

На полях ввода растягивай виджет так чтоб он занял нужное количество колонок, если надо расположить один под другим. В коде это параметр [columnSpan](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgridlayout.html#addWidget-2)